# Deploying .ear file (contains rest services)

Tags: rest, jboss, ear, jboss6.x

I have a few questions about deploying my .ear file (was provided to me, the file itself should not be the problem). I set up jBoss application server jboss-6.0.0.Final and was able to run a simple hello world app to ensure the server was functioning properly.

I was told to place the .ear file in /server/default/deploy so I did. When I ran jboss (through /bin/run.bat) I got no errors related to deploying the ear file.

Question

1. Is this all the software I need (jBoss)? Do I also need something like Apache or tomcat?
2. The .ear file contains RESTful service calls that should return xml. Will these be deployed (accessible through a jQuery ajax call after the server (jboss/bin/run.bat) is executed?

Currently when I try to make the calls, the resources do not seem to exist.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS ships with an embedded Tomcat as a servlet container so you really don't need that anymore. Apache Web Server is NOT required for your .EAR to be deployed properly.

To answer your questions

1. No other software is needed to deploy the EAR. You simply copy your EAR file to deploy directory (which you have rightfully done so).
2. If your EAR contains RESTFul services, they will be deployed and you can access them using any client including jQuery or even a simple browsers. The trick is to know the access URL to the RESTFul services.

If you have difficulty identifying the URL for accessing your RESTFul services please refer [1] for more information.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JAX-RS+Reference+Guide

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was given a list of the call included in the .ear file. They were localhost:8443, should I change these to :8080?

Comment: If you have HTTPS (SSL) setup then you can still use localhost:8443 otherwise you'll have to use localhost:8080.

Comment: I don't think I do. Just to confirm what I read on other tutorials. All I need to do is put the ear file in the deploy folder and start with bin\run.bat. (It is hard to tell if the file was properly deployed in the console that opens from run.bat. If I go to localhost:8080 nothing is there (does jBoos have a "home page" like Apache would?) Thanks!

Comment: If you do not see any errors, most probably the EAR just deployed fine. You should be able to login to the admin console "localhost:8080/admin-console" and see your deployments there.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first question. You need apache if you want to serve static content or you need to isolate the traffic (say keep apache in the dmz and then use apache to proxy traffic to the internal jboss servers). tomcat is bundled along with jboss, so you do not need it.